# Audio without X

Tags: command-line, pulseaudio, alsa, headless

Crosspost from /r/linuxquestions:

I am trying to convert my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop into a headless server and need everything running without X needing to start. I've gotten the partitions to mount automatically, etc. but after changing the Grub option, to:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"

When I SSH into the server, there is no audio out. Normally I can control it with mocp via SSH and use the mocp volume control. Without X, there is no sound output. Alsamixer won't run without sudo, but it looks like Pulseaudio is already running (tried rebooting).

Running Alsamixer with sudo, confirms that all channels are turned up. I'm sure I'm missing a simple step here, but I can't think of what it is, can anybody offer some insight?

---

In addition, it was suggested that I try adding myself to the 'audio' group. The groups output is:

```
 SkyCaptain adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare
```

Running

```
sudo usermod -a -G audio SkyCaptain
```

does not change the output but returns no error

EDIT:

I've discovered that playing audio as root DOES work as expected. Adding myself to the audio group allows me to run Alsamixer as regular user, but no channels are muted and the audio still does not work

Comment: I would like to know if you are trying to get audio from the SSH connection and what are you trying to liste?

Comment: I'm trying to output the audio on the local (server's) speakers (the server is in the next room)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by logging in with X and disabling all these settings I'd added in paprefs/pavucontrol to get RTP streaming working. Looks like that solved the issue. Thanks for everybody's help!